# How to start count down timer after clicking a button in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

my count down timer starts once I load the page. But what I want is that the timer should start after clicking the button.

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TimeAllSecondes > 0)
        {
            TimeAllSecondes = TimeAllSecondes - 1;
        }

        TimeSpan time_Span = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeAllSecondes);
        hh = time_Span.Hours;
        mm = time_Span.Minutes;
        ss = time_Span.Seconds;

        Label2.Text = "  " + hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
    }
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

     }
```

Comment: How are you starting it in page load? How are you using timer in web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the Timer control in Design-Time, eg:

```
 runat="server" Interval="2000" Enabled="False" />
```

Then Enable it in the Button_Click:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

You would be better off doing this in Javascript unless timing server-side (safe from client-side manipulations) is important.

Comment: Glad to hear, can you tick the holo checkbox to the left of this answer, it will give you a couple of points and let everyone know your problem is solved.

Comment: @JeremyThompson when I am using this then timer_tick doesn't working. Please help

Comment: @ManishJain - have you read the [FAQ]'s, or the [tour], or [ask], or even provide the error? C'mon you've been around long enough **NOT** to randomly tell someone "it doesn't work" - WOMM- [mcve] - new question

Comment: @JeremyThompson I didn't told you that I got any error or your solution is not working. I just told you that after enable inside button click; breakpoint in  timer_tick doesn't come.